# Why is the brace-or-equal initializer brace-or-equal?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S {
    //std::vector<int> ns(1); //ERROR!
    std::vector<int> ns = std::vector<int>(1);
};

int main() {
    S s;
    std::cout << (s.ns[0] = 123) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Using the parentheses initializer seems to be an error. What is the purpose behind this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea is to flat out reject any syntax that could be interpreted as a function declaration. For example,

```
std::vector<int> ns();
```

is a function declaration. These aren't:

```
std::vector<int> ns{};
std::vector<int> ns = std::vector<int>();
```

For consistency, any member declaration with this form

```
T t(args...);
```

is disallowed, which avoids a repeat of the *most vexing parse* fiasco.

Comment: Why would you write `T t();` instead of `T t;`?

Comment: @xiver77 This is value initialization vs. default initialization. If `T` is an built-in type, or an aggregate with built-in members, it makes a difference: value initialization leads to zero initialization, and default initialization doesn't.